# Hidden field value not accessible from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have hidden field,

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
```

I am setting value of hidden field in code behind file in `videoFile_UploadedComplete` event (AsyncFileUpload control's event)

`HiddenField1.Value = "yespost";`

I am trying to access value in javascript,

```
 if (document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>").value == "yespost")
```

Its giving empty string ("").

I am calling script on  OnClientUploadComplete event.

Note: First server side event gets executed and client side so value is set first.

Help needed

Comment: Did you try giving the ID as it is in getElementById? eg. document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value

Answer (score 0):

You want to select by id. Add a '#' before your selector:

```
if (document.getElementById("#<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>").value == "yespost")
```

Comment: I tried it says, Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: How is the element rendered on the page? Are you executing your JavaScript AFTER the element is rendered?

Comment: yes, executing my JavaScript AFTER the element is rendered

Comment: is the HiddenField1.ClientID the same as "HiddenField1"?

Comment: For asp.net server controls we use <id>.ClientID to access control using javascript. for HTML we can use "<id>"

Comment: Then shouldn't the selector be `document.getElementById("#HiddenField1")`?